# Performing xor in python on 3 bits, but output is 6 bits

Tags: python

I am performing an xor operation on 000 and 111 in python. I would expect this to output 3 bits, like this:

```
One: 1 1 1
Two: 0 0 0
XOR: 1 1 1
```

Instead, it outputs 6 bits. What's happening?

```
print '{0:b}'.format(000^111)
'1101111'
```

Comment: `0b111 != 111`. `'{0:b}'.format(0^0b111)` gives the desired result.

Comment: `bin(111) == '0b1101111'`. And be careful with leading zeros - they mean octal in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `000` and `111` as they are, they are read as normal integers, and the operation you're performing is `0^1101111`, which, obviously, is `1101111` (in binary).

To use binary `111`, you'd use `0bxxxx` form (similar to how `0x___` is for hexadecimals):

```
print '{0:b}'.format(0b0^0b111)
```